# Android Studio: Rendering Problems with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

When I set a CoordinatorLayout as my root element I get the following error when Android Studio is rendering a preview.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:413)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:177)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:214)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:142)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:413)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:497)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:894)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:590)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:644)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:586)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:581)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

My layout file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/detail_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
        android:background="@color/background_light"
        android:paddingTop="36dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.godine"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}  

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

    ...
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong here?

**Edit**
As @deniz already mentioned in an answer the preview works with the newest update of the Android Studio

Comment: have u added the library in gradle??

Comment: why do you have 2 namespace(xmlns)

Comment: @war_Hero the second namespace is for design support library properties

Comment: Check my answer before switching to Beta channel or M preview.

Comment: @Campiador thanks for your answer. I just tried and and it works!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a known issue in the Android Open Source Project Issue Tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175595

The unfortunate workaround described by the Android project member is:

> Workarounds: Try rendering with M preview using AS v1.3 preview **OR** use `FrameLayout` for designing and change to `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` while debugging.

Answer (score 4):

Update android studio to latest version (beta) 1.3 beta version.Menu -> 'Check for updates'

If you are not able to find the beta update change android studio settings(***Updates***), then update that patch and render with M preview

[image]

Try Renderring your preview using Android M preview.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I solved the similar error of `android...coordinatorlayout` that appear instead of the preview of android app by:

1- Close the project

2- Restart the android studio

3- Build the project

May be it will help someone.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue **after updating to Android Studio 4.0.1** and solved it by disabling Experimental Layout Rendering Engine and restarting Android Studio. do as this to solve:
go to **`File->Settings->Experimental->Editor-> and uncheck the Use new Layout Rendering Engine`** then hit OK and restart Android Studio. you should find it working seamlessly
hope this solution helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Wait! **Do not switch to beta channel.**

As of July 29, Android Studio 1.3 has been released on stable channel. I checked, and can confirm that the new version of the IDE completely addresses your issue in question with `CoordinatorLayout` rendering.

Android Studio 1.3 is not yet published on the Android website, nonetheless, you can upgrade your Android Studio from 1.2 to 1.3 by downloading the update patch through the IDE menu. Simply click on:

> Help --> Check for Update --> Update and Restart

P.S. You do not need Android M to render either. Lower APIs work just as well.

Comment: I got the version 1.3 and still not rendering the CoordinateLayout :/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem again myself.

I ran `clean project` -> `restart android studio` -> `build again` and it worked for me.

I assume Android Studio had some weird cache with AndroidX and the old support library.

10/10 good build tools.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with `AppBarLayout`, it seems IDE cached some wrong version of widget.

`File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart` helped me.