# The rendering library could not be initialized in Latest Android Studio Version 4.0

Tags: android, xml, layout, rendering

com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.RenderingException: [The rendering library could not be initialized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dra0.png)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibraryLoader.loadImpl(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:89)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibraryLoader.load(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:115)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:174)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$RenderTaskBuilder.lambda$build$0(RenderService.java:581)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Please also check the image, I cannot use Layout components. If anybody can help me with this issue will be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852844/android-studio-rendering-problems-with-coordinatorlayout